# Open in emacs: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refuse it

Tags: emacs, emacs24

I have followed [post](http://www.johndcook.com/emacs_windows.html#explorer) to enable emacs in windows explorer by adding following registry:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open In Emacs]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open In Emacs\Command]
@="\"C:\\Unix-Bin\\emacs-24.3\\bin\\emacsclientw.exe\" -a \"C:\\Unix-Bin\\emacs-24.3\\bin\\runemacs.exe\" \"%1\""
```

Before today it works good. But  today I find when to open file with "Open in Emacs" menu, following 
error will popup. And later the file is opened by emacs correctly.

No idea why following error come out.

Error :

```
C:\Unix-Bin\emacs-24.3\bin\emacsclientw.exe: connect: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refuse it.
```

[image]

Comment: Have you changed your firewall settings, or installed a new anti-virus (so that something has closed the port emacs-server uses)?

Comment: Not sure. But I remember I haven't change firewall and no new anti-virus installed.  Do you know how to check if emacs-server port closed or not?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had the same error message. In my case I had to delete the old connection: I removed

```
~/emacs.d/server/server
```

file and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Grab this [bat file](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RobertAdesamEmacsClientBat), then add these lines:

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set serverfile="%userprofile%\.emacs.d\server\server"
if exist %serverfile% (
  set /p first= < %serverfile%
  for /f "tokens=2" %%a in ("!first!") do ( set server=%%a )
  tasklist /nh /fi "PID eq !server!" 2>&1 | findstr /C:"emacs.exe" >nul 2>&1
  if ERRORLEVEL 1  del /f %serverfile% 
)
```

after the `@echo off` line.